# How to tokenize a column with variable length string

Tags: java, sql, oracle, plsql

I have a question regarding tokenizing string in a column
I have table like

```
id  list
1   i love dogs
2   i like cats and dogs
```

and so on

it should be converted to

```
id  list
1   i
1   love
1   dogs
2   i
2   like
2   cates
2   and
2   dogs
```

How do I tokenize this? I tried using this code inside cursor and procedure

```sql
SELECT id, regexp_substr(str, '[^ ]+', 1, level) TOKEN
    from test
CONNECT by level <= length(regexp_replace (str, '[^ ]+')) + 1;
```

but this is very slow when called from java. Is there any other alternative?

Thanks
Anil

Comment: Your question is not readable. How is the table structure?

Comment: I am not able to write it properly here in tabular form 

id 1 has string "i love dogs"

id 2 has string "i like cats and dogs"

I want it like 

each row would have same id and individual word 

like first row will be 1 i second will be 1 love and similarly

Comment: don't comment, it's not readable, edit your question!

Comment: @user2780212 You can enclose output in `pre` tag, and to format the code, select it and press the `{}` button, or tab it with 4 spaces. If you know that words will separated by one space, you could change the `SELECT` to just return the whole string, and then, in PL/SQL, loop through it and get each token with `substr` function and use `instr` to search for ending of each word. Should be faster then `regexp_substr`.

Comment: @PrzemyslawKruglej , even if I do that i need to use select statement to insert the result into a new table. the problem I think is with connect and by level which is making it too slow.
Is there any way I can avoid that. 

Also I didnt get when you said just return the whole string. small code snnippet might help.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using this in Oracle or solely in Java... if you just have the string in Java I imagine it'd be quicker to tokenize there...

Answer (score 1):

As I've mentioned in the comment, you could try using the `substr` and `instr` functions instead of `regexp_substr`, perhaps performance will be acceptable for you:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test_list_tab (
  id NUMBER,
  str VARCHAR2(100)
);

CREATE TABLE test_tokens_tab (
  id NUMBER,
  token VARCHAR2(100)
);

INSERT INTO test_list_tab VALUES (1, 'i love dogs');
INSERT INTO test_list_tab VALUES (2, 'i like cats and dogs');
INSERT INTO test_list_tab VALUES (3, 'i');
INSERT INTO test_list_tab VALUES (4, 'abc');
INSERT INTO test_list_tab VALUES (5, 'abc i');
INSERT INTO test_list_tab VALUES (6, NULL);

DECLARE
  v_token test_list_tab.str%TYPE;
  v_space_position NUMBER := 1;
  v_prev_space_position NUMBER := 1;
BEGIN
  FOR v_rec IN (SELECT id, str FROM test_list_tab WHERE str IS NOT NULL)
  LOOP
    v_prev_space_position := 0;

    LOOP
      v_space_position := instr(v_rec.str, ' ', v_prev_space_position + 1);
      IF v_space_position > 0 THEN
        v_token := substr(v_rec.str, v_prev_space_position + 1, v_space_position - v_prev_space_position - 1);
      ELSE
        v_token := substr(v_rec.str, v_prev_space_position + 1);
      END IF;

      INSERT INTO test_tokens_tab VALUES (v_rec.id, v_token);

      v_prev_space_position := v_space_position;
      EXIT WHEN v_space_position = 0;
    END LOOP;
  END LOOP;

  COMMIT;
END;

SELECT id, token FROM test_tokens_tab;
```

Output:

```
        ID TOKEN 
---------- -------
         1 i       
         1 love    
         1 dogs    
         2 i       
         2 like    
         2 cats    
         2 and     
         2 dogs    
         3 i       
         4 abc     
         5 abc     
         5 i
```

Comment: THanks @Przemyslaw Kruglej , The culprit was connect by level and regexp, This query is faster. I will try to run it for million records that I have.